# editor is utf8, javascript spec expects utf16

Tags: javascript, utf-8, utf-16

The ECMAScript spec says the following:

> When a String contains actual textual data, each element is considered to be a single UTF-16 code unit. Whether or not this is the actual storage format of a String, the characters within a String are numbered by their initial code unit element position as though they were represented using UTF-16. All operations on Strings (except as otherwise stated) treat them as sequences of undifferentiated 16-bit unsigned integers; they do not ensure the resulting String is in normalised form, nor do they ensure language-sensitive results.

source: http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.4

I've been writing javascript for years with my editor configured in utf8 encoding. Why have I never encountered a problem with strings? I am shipping mostly code in plain english with the ocasional emoji.
Why have I never encountered a problem with my code being utf8 encoded, while the spec says you need utf16?

Comment: Strings and your code are different.

Comment: Because it is downward-compatible? If the other way around, it may break.

Comment: Same section *The intent is that textual data coming into the execution environment from outside (e.g., user input, text read from a file or received over the network, etc.) be converted to Unicode Normalised Form C before the running program sees it.* so it doesn't matter what is in your file the execution environment will convert it to UTF-16 before anything is done with it

Answer (score 1):

You are citing the section about the string type, which is about the runtime representation of strings that JavaScript code works with - e.g. it says how a `charAt` call should behave.

The textual format and encoding of JavaScript source code is a totally different matter. You would need to read [section 6, *Source Text*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-6), for that. Admittedly, it says that the parser operates on 16-bit code units of text as well (however it assumes they are unicode-normalised). It also states

> If an actual source text is encoded in a form other than 16-bit code units it must be processed as if it was first converted to UTF-16.

So when you send JS files encoded as UTF-8 (which is pretty much the standard) and send the appropriate headers, then the browser will decode the UTF-8 and parse the result according to the grammar rules.